# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE lines starting by issue

Tags: mysql, csv

I have csv file with over a million lines and i need to write only the lines starting by '01' into database.

.csv file looks like this

```
01;104;5586;20;1000;
01;105;5586;80;1000;
01;106;5586;80;1000;
04;104;5586;20;1000;
06;105;5586;80;1000;
05;106;5586;80;1000;
```

SQL looks linke this

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$uploadfile' 
    REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES  
    (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`);
```

So this works to import all lines. But how can i get only the lines which start with 01;....

Comment: So are you saying that all rows are being read into your table?  Are you sure that this problem is reproducible?

Comment: I can write line by line into db, but it is causing issues because the are so many lines (more than one million). I only want the lines with 01 at start and write them in the database

Comment: i edited my original post which works for all lines, but i need those starting with 01;... and ignore others

Comment: From the manual If all the lines you want to read in have a common prefix that you want to ignore, you can use LINES STARTING BY 'prefix_string' to skip over the prefix, and anything before it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html. Is this what you want?

Comment: No i guess in need to find another solutions to import a large CSV file and be able to skip rows on import

Comment: I don't know exactly what you've tried, and what isn't working for you, but what is wrong with just reading in the entire CSV file and then deleting the records you don't want?  Are you working under strict memory limitations or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one -

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES STARTING BY '01' TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`)
  SET `a` = '01';
```

and you will get something like this -

```
01  104 5586    20  1000
01  105 5586    80  1000
01  106 5586    80  1000
```

Check line separator you use - '\r\n' or '\n' in TERMINATED BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Devart's solution would work if the data in the line never contains "01" again.

I found out that LINES STARTING BY is not working as expected according to this article:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3632

> "Another problem was that LINES STARTING BY xxx means that the MySQL will assume the lines start is at the next occurence of xxx".

So if my data also include 01, not just the start of the line, MySQL read some data from these lines. So this will insert bad data:

```
01;104;5586;01;1000
01;105;8586;80;1000
01;106;5586;80:0123
```

I wonder why there is no solution like the suggetions in the article from 2012:

> (1) let LINES STARTING BY 'X' continue to mean "line contains 'X' anywhere and data prior to 'X' in the record is skipped" and document this as such.
>
> (2) add LINES STARTING BY 'X' POSITION N which means "line contains 'X' beginning at character position N relative to the beginning of the record.

I ended up spliting the files or adding a prefix (X) at the start of each line.

The .csv like this

```
X01;104;5586;20;1000;
X01;105;5586;01;1000;
X01;106;5586;80;1000;
X04;104;5586;01;0123;
X06;105;5586;80;1000;
X05;106;5586;80;1000;
```

And the code like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES STARTING BY 'X01' TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) SET `a` = '01';
```

Maybe someone else out there had the same missunderstanding with LINES STARTING BY.